# How to select last div in a container div?

Tags: html, css

I would like to select with CSS and apply some background color ONLY on the row number 3.
But I have a limitation that I cannot use a css selector which select using a class name.

Could you please point me out to solve this issue? Thanks!

```html
<div class="root">
  <div class="row">1
  </div>
  <div class="row">2
  </div>
  <div class="row">3
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "I cannot use a css selector which select using a class name"? Does that mean you can't use `.row:last-child`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use

```css
.root>div:last-child {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="root">
  <div class="row">1
  </div>
  <div class="row">2
  </div>
  <div class="row">3
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can I select the last item directory from .row class?

Comment: Yes, it is ```.row:last-child```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```css
.root div:last-child {
  background: red;
}
.root div:nth-child(1) {
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="root">
  <div class="row">1
  </div>
  <div class="row">2
  </div>
  <div class="row">3
  </div>
</div>
```

If you plan to select row 3, and decide to add more rows you can use nth-child(3)

Answer (score 0):

div.root:last-child will select every children.

Try this Instead:

```
div.root div:last-child{
  background: green;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in different ways:

```css
.root div.row:last-child {
  background:red;
}

.root div.row:last-of-type {
  background: green;
}

.root div.row:nth-last-child(1) {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="root">
  <div class="row">1
  </div>
  <div class="row">2
  </div>
  <div class="row">3
  </div>
</div>
```